# Regular expression match count in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am matching a string of the form A<=>B!C<=>D!E<=>F... and want to do checks on the letters. Basically I want to tell if the letters are in the class according to a hash I have defined. I had the idea of doing the following regex and then looping through the matched strings:

```
$a =~ /(.)<=>(.)/g;
```

But I can't figure out to tell how many $1, $2 variables have matched. How do I know how many there are? Also, is there a better way to do this? I am using Perl 5.8.8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want the 'countof' operator to count the number of matches:

```
my $count = () = $string =~ /(.)<=>(.)/g;
```

Replacing the empty list with an array will retain the matches:

```
my @matches = $string =~ /(.)<=>(.)/g;
```

Which provides another way to get the `$count`:

```
my $count = @matches;   # scalar @matches works too
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %letters = map { $_ => 1 } qw(A C F);
my $s = 'A<=>B!C<=>D!E<=>F';
while ($s =~ /(.)<=>(.)/g) {
    print "$1\n" if exists $letters{$1};
    print "$2\n" if exists $letters{$2};    
}

__END__

A
C
F
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and increment it each time you go through your loop?

Comment: Yes but what are the bounds on my loop? I could take the length of the string and divide but I was hoping for a more general solution.

Comment: You don't need bounds if you use the proper kind of loop, as toolic's answer shows.